# Simple jQuery Slider/Carousel for Content with Left/Right Arrows & No-Autoplay

Tags: jquery, slider, carousel

I'm trying to make a simple jQuery slider/carousel with controls. I want to **slide in or out** 3 divs when clicking on left and right arrows. I don't need autoplay for now. Just want to say that I tried many plugins and tutorials online. I also searched stackoverflow for answers, but they don't solve my case. So...

This is my **HTML** (simplified):

```
<div class="slider">
<div class="wrap-12">

    <div class="slides">
        <div class="slide name1"><!-- stuff --></div>
        <div class="slide name2"><!-- stuff --></div>
        <div class="slide name3"><!-- stuff --></div>
    </div>

    <div class="controls">
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="right"></div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

And **CSS**:

```
.slider .slides {
    width: 1020px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 0;
}

.slider .slide {
    width: 1020px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

To move to slide 2, first div needs `margin-left: -100%` applied, to move to slide 3 (still first slide) needs `margin-left: -200%` applied, to 4 `-300%`...

Very basic **jQuery** code I got:

```
// slider
// cache the DOM
var $slide = $('.slider .slide').first();
var snum = 1; // wanted to use for slide number

// next
$('.slider .right').click(function(){
  $slide.animate({'margin-left': '-=100%'}, 600, function(){
    // function after clicked right arrow, doesn't have to be here if there is a simple way of doing it :P
  });
});

// prev
$('.slider .left').click(function(){
  $slide.animate({'margin-left': '+=100%'}, 600, function(){
    // function after clicked left arrow
  });
});
```

All this does is when I click on left arrow it slides to slide 2, 3... When I click left it goes back one slide. It doesn't stop when I hit last slide nor first. I also want this code to give active slide (one that we're sliding to) `active-in` class, previous slide: `out` class. Also active slide needs to pass its second class ex. `name3` class to body tag `<body class="name3">`. After jQuery visit it should look like this:

```
<body class="name3">
    <!-- (...) -->
    <div class="slide name1"></div>
    <div class="slide name2 out"></div>
    <div class="slide name3 active-in"></div>
```

I hope it isn't too hard to do or impossible to do with jQuery. Of course, you don't need to use my jQuery code as a base, if there is a simpler & shorter way to do it with your code. Brief explanation would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

May i suggest using jQuery Cycle 2.0

Add this to where you want your slider to be

```
<div id=outside>

    <!-- prev/next links -->
    <div class=center>
        <span id=prev>Prev</span>
        <span id=next>Next</span>
    </div>


    <!-- slideshow -->
    <div class="cycle-slideshow" 
        data-cycle-timeout=0 <!-- change this to whatever you want the interval to be for changing slides e.g (4000 = 4s) -->
        data-cycle-prev="#prev"
        data-cycle-next="#next"
        >

        <div class="slide name1"><!-- stuff --></div>
        <div class="slide name2"><!-- stuff --></div>
        <div class="slide name3"><!-- stuff --></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Add this near the  tag

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
```

Cycle 2.0 Link :

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/

On a side note if you decide to use cycle 2.0 add this to your css to stop images flashing on load

```
.cycle-slideshow div {
   display: none;
}

.cycle-slideshow div.cycle-sentinel{
   display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd prefer to not use plugins. jQuery cycle has way too many options than I need.